# Eclipse plugin developement : Schematic Editor

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to develop an Eclipse plug-in as a schematic editor in Eclipse. So some questions concerning this.

1. Is it possible to draw geometrical objects (rectangle/line/triangle/etc) using Eclipse **native** API ? If not please suggest alternative methods of doing it.
2. Are there C++ APIs for doing this, preferably **native Eclipse** ?

Regards,
Levon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, unless you consider adding the **[plugin GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/)** as native Eclipse.
   "The Graphical Editing Framework (GEF) provides technology to create rich graphical editors and views for the Eclipse Workbench UI."
2. Eclipse being developed mainly in Java, I doubt there is C++ APIs for this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would evaluate EMF + GMF + GEF combination as they can be used to generate the diagram for your domain model. Check the [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-gmf/).